# How can one get local host address in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

In a route (that exposes a REST service) i need to get the local host address/domain (so as I can build links to be included in a response body)

Is there a way to get the local host address from within camel ?

PS : running camel inside servicemix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there isn't a Camel specific way (that I know of), I'd just use an external property file to configure environment specific settings like this...you can then use [camel properties](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) to pull this in, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea when posting questions is to provide more details.
Which camel component do you use for REST. And which version of SMX/Camel do you use etc.
As you question assume that the rest component in Camel will expose a hostname information.

This questions is not Camel specific per see, as you can use the regular Java API to get the hostname.

Comment: Well I added that I am using rest just for info. I am trying to get the hostname from inside a Processor. I just thought I might get that hostname from exchange properties or camel context. Thank you Claus !